# How to shorten the length of the url while uploading the image using fileread directive?

Tags: angularjs

When we push The Image Store the url in base 64 format, it becomes very big. How to shorten this base 64 url ?
 I am using the file read directive for uploading the image. Check the plunker. Please help how to do this.

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
<input type="file" name="image" ng-model="companyItem" fileread="companyItem" required>
<img ng-src="{{companyItem}}" style="width:100px;height:100px"/> 
 <button type="button" ng-click="save(companyItem)">save</button>
 <script>
 app.controller("MainController",function($scope){
   $scope.data=[]
   $scope.companyItem={}
   $scope.save=function(companyItem){
     $scope.data.push($scope.companyItem)
     console.log($scope.data)
     $scope.companyItem={}
   }
 })
</script>
</body>
```

Script

```
var app=angular.module("select",[]);

app.directive("fileread", [function () {
return {
   scope: {
       fileread: "="
   },
   link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
       element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
               scope.$apply(function () {
                   scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
               });
           }
           reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
       });
     }
   }
}]);
```

`https://plnkr.co/edit/JRxB4uNlCbBrkfkwUwMv?p=preview

Comment: Well, Its not the URL you are receiving that is long. It the encoded base64 string for your image. And It cannot be shortened as far as I know.

Comment: What is the problem with the base64 string?

Comment: it takes nearly two pages of string